# How to transfer SPSS data file directly to a Matlab matrix and vice versa?

Tags: matlab, matrix, statistics, spss

Does anyone know what is the best way to transfer an SPSS .sav or any other SPSS Data file in a Matlab matrix and vice versa? (maybe directly)

The only way I found was this:

1. Saved SPSS dataset as an Excel file.
2. Opened the excel file in Matlab workspace.
3. Read the excel file in Matlab-matrix (A) via: `A = readxls('filename.xlsx')`

I am looking for a direct way to bring/convert SPSS numeric dataset in a Matlab matrix and vice versus.

From Matlab to SPSS I have exported my Matlab-matrix in a .txt file and opened it SPSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for [PSPP](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/)*, that might be good for SPSS as well. The idea is simple - do what you describe in the question, but in an automated manner.

Start by writing a script file for SPSS (the following is for PSPP, but should be very similar to SPSS):

```
GET FILE =  'your_SPSS_file_with_full_path.sav'
save translate
        /outfile = 'your_resulted_CSV_file_with_full_path.csv'
        /type = CSV
        /REPLACE
        /FIELDNAMES
        /CELLS=LABELS.
```

write `CELLS=VALUES` if you want the numeric value and not the lables.

Save this file (let's say it's called spss2csv.sps).

In Matlab, write the following:

```
sps_file_name = 'full_path\spss2csv.sps';
% replace the path below with the path for SPSS:
command = ['"C:\Program Files\PSPP\bin\pspp.exe" ' sps_file_name];
system(command)
```

This will generate a .csv file, that you can import to Matlab either by [`xlsread`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/xlsread.html) or by using the [import tool](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importtool-app.html):

```
uiimport(your_resulted_CSV_file_with_full_path.csv)
```

This tool lets you import mixed data, and generate a script so that could be done automatically the next time.

For the opposite direction (Matlab to SPSS) take a look at these submissions to File Exchange:

1. [export data to spss](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29442-export-data-to-spss---pasw).
2. [save4spss](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8659-save4spss).

<sub>*[PSPP](https://www.gnu.org/software/pspp/) is free and works extremely fast, so if you can't implement this in SPSS just download it.</sub>

---

Here is a function that you can use in Matlab if you install PSPP, without getting out of Matlab at all:

```
function import_sav(sav_file,labels)
% Opens the import tool for importins a sav file
% 'sav_file' is the name of the SPSS\PSPP file to import
% 'labels' is a logical that if true then the file is imported using the
% labels and not the numeric values. Default is TRUE.

if nargin<2
    labels = true;
end
[p,csv_file] = fileparts(sav_file);
if isempty(p), p = cd; end
sps_file = [p '\convert2csv.sps'];
% sav_file = 'C:\Users\Eyal\Dropbox\MATLAB\atid\result.sav';
csv_file = [p '\' csv_file '.csv'];
fid = fopen(sps_file,'w');
fprintf(fid,'GET FILE =  ''%s''\n',sav_file);
fprintf(fid,'save translate\n');
fprintf(fid,'\t\t/outfile = ''%s''\n',csv_file);
fprintf(fid,'\t\t/type = CSV\n');
fprintf(fid,'\t\t/REPLACE\n');
fprintf(fid,'\t\t/FIELDNAMES\n');
if labels
    fprintf(fid,'\t\t/CELLS=LABELS.\n');
else
    fprintf(fid,'\t\t/CELLS=VALUES.\n');
end
fclose(fid);
command = ['"C:\Program Files\PSPP\bin\pspp.exe" ' sps_file];
system(command)
uiimport(csv_file)
end
```

This will automatically open the data import tool for that .sav file that you enter when calling the function: `import_sav('my_file.sav',1)`.

Answer (score 0):

If Matlab supports ODBC for input and you can get the SPSS ODBC driver,you could  issue an ODBC query directly against the SAV file.

Comment: Matlab does [support ODBC](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/ug/importing-data-from-databases-into-matlab.html) but the OP  will need the [Database toolbox](https://www.mathworks.com/help/database/index.html) for this capability. Also, I'm not sure this option is open under the core license of SPSS.

Comment: I think the driver is free and probably included in the Data Access Pack, which is licensed with the Base product.